# Application_Error takes precedence over Page_Error

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have both Page_Error method in page that raises error, and Application_Error in global.asax. When Page throws exception, executed routine is Application_Error. But for that one particular page I would like to have different handling in Page_Error. Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks, 
Pawel

P.S. Perhaps it is because exception being thrown is caused by too large file being uploaded (I tested file upload page how it handles files bigger then web.config setting) and Page_Error is not yet wired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same the function of Page_Error you can check for the page and if is the one you look you have diferent behavior.

```
if( HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("YourFileName.axd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   // the diferent way
}
else
{

}
```

The next way is from inside the page with the diferent behavior.

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        // here is the different, since you catch here is not move to the Page_Error
        // except is a code error... in any case you can do an extra error clear.
    }
}
```

Comment: ProcessRequest worked smoothly. Still I'm supprised that Page_Error and Application_Error worked for me that way. Perhaps it was because exception being thrown was caused by too large file being uploaded (I tested file upload page how it handles files bigger then web.config setting)?

Comment: @dragonfly yes web.config settings, if I remeber the default limit is 2Mg

Comment: Limit is not the issue here. I deliberately uploaded big file to test it against web.config setting. I wanted to handler ASP .NET runtime error in Page_Error method, but it never gets called.